# Unable to use shared library in webpack with pnpm monorepo MFE

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

Our team is trying to build a MFE React application using `webpack` module federation. Currently we are using `pnpm workspaces` with a monorepo architecture. The project has following folders

1. `apps` - This folder contains all the executables applications
2. `packages` -  This folder contains the shared libraries like design-system, icons that would be re-used in the different mfe applications.

Folder structure

apps
|---app1
|------ .....
|------ package.json
|---app2
|------ .....
|------ package.json
|---app3
|------ .....
|------ package.json
packages
|---package-1
|------ .....
|------ package.json
|---package-2
|------ .....
|------ package.json
configs
...
...
package.json

When we are trying use the exported `package` in the `apps` folder there are no build time errors and able to navigate to the definitions directly from the app.

But when we run the application, the webpack throws error as shown below:

[image]

Can someone please help us with this issue?

Thanks in advance :-)